# ExtJs maxlength with custom message

Tags: javascript, extjs

I've added a maxLength in a sencha textareafield and this is my code:

```
{
    xtype: 'textareafield', 
    fieldLabel: 'SMS Template', 
    maxLength: 160,
    msgTarget: 'under',
    reference: 'fldSMSTemplateMessage'                          
}
```

it works as expected and i get this default message:

[image: default error message example]

Is it possible to override this message?
Or should I validate the field manually?

I'm using extjs 6.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [maxLength](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Text.html#cfg-maxLengthText) config that you can override.

Note that the config is passed through [Ext.String.format](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/classic/Ext.String.html#method-format), and you can have `{0}` in your override to reference `maxLength` value.

Comment: I read that doc and... I actually misinterpreted the meaning of "maxLengthText" for some reason... well thank you very much! It works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```js
{
    xtype: 'textareafield',
    anchor: '100%',
    fieldLabel: 'Label',
    maxLength: 160,
    maxLengthText: '{0} is the max length of this field'
}
```